# How to use Dagger2 in Android to inject activity objects easier?

Tags: android, dagger-2

On Android, When using Dagger2, I have to call the following line on every activities that uses `apiService`:

```
@Inject
public ApiService apiService;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                      .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
                      .build()
                      .inject(this);

    //...
}
```

How can I summarize it to something like:

```
DaggerApiComponent.builder()
                  .activity(this)
                  .build()
                  .inject(this);
```

or even simpler to something like:

```
MyApplication.injectApiService(this);
```

How should I change my component and modules to use Dagger2 with less copy-pasting code in my activities?

Here is my `ApiComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApiModule.class)
public interface ApiComponent {

    void inject(MainActivity activity);
    void inject(...
}
```

Here is `ApiModule`:

```
@Module(includes = {RetrofitModule.class, ActivityModule.class})
public class ApiModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public static ApiService provideApiService(Activity activity) {
        //...
    }
}
```

and `ActivityModule`:

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    private final Activity context;

    public ActivityModule(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public Activity provideActivityContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach of such "DI" has two problems:

- like what the OP said: we need to copy & paste this boilerplate wherever we need injection, which is tedious and hard to refactor.
- Injectee (e.g. `Activity`) should not know where the `@Inject` instance is from, what it cares about is just "hey, give me an instance of it".

To resolve above problems, `dagger.android` comes to the rescue.

1. Create `AndroidInjector` for each component.

```
// App component
@Singleton
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class, // build-in module
        ActivityBindingModule::class,            
        AppModule::class
    ]
)
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {
    // we need to bind `MainApplication` instance to this component,
    // so we have a builder here.
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder : AndroidInjector.Builder<MainApplication>()
}
```

```
// Each controller (e.g. `Activity` / `Fragment` / `Service`) subcomponents
@Module
abstract class ActivityBindingModule {
    // will generate a FooActivitySubcomponent under ActivityBindingModule's component
    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FooModule::class])
    internal abstract fun fooActivity(): FooActivity

    @ActivityScoped
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [BarModule::class])
    internal abstract fun barActivity(): BarActivity
}
```

2. Wire up your `AndroidInjector`s, so it can do injection for us using provided injector in step 1.

```
// App component
class MainApplication : DaggerApplication() {

    override fun applicationInjector(): AndroidInjector<out DaggerApplication> {
        return DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this)
    }
}
```

```
// Each controller subcomponents
class FooActivity : DaggerAppCompatActivity() {
    @Inject lateinit var foo: Foo

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState) 
        // no need to call inject() here anymore!
        foo.doSth()
    }
}
```

*For a concrete example: check out [iosched](https://github.com/google/iosched)*

Comment: My `ApiModule` depends on `activity context` how can I provide activity in this way?
I get this error: `[Dagger/MissingBinding] [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.app.Activity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or an @Provides-annotated method.
android.app.Activity is injected at...`

Comment: I added `@Binds abstract Activity bindMainActivity(MainActivity activity);` in a subclass module inside `ActivityBindingModule` and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Android Activity injector, the usage is described well [here](https://medium.com/@iammert/new-android-injector-with-dagger-2-part-1-8baa60152abe).